# Scanning with MX920

Tags: scanning

I have a Canon MX922 printer /scanner. The printer stopped printing because Im supposedly out of ink from cartridge 250 PGBK.

Is there a way to cheat the machine into thinking there is ink let so I can continue scanning my work?

Comment: http://www.technipages.com/canon-pixma-mg5220-scan-without-ink/amp